# Rails cookie that expires as soon as browser closes?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-on-rails-6

What is the difference between

```
    cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
```

and

```
    cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
```

in rails?

How do I set a cookies that expires as soon as browser closes like session?

My sessions controller:

```
   class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])

        if params[:remember_me]
          cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
        else
           cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
        end 
        redirect_to user
        flash[:success] = 'Logged in successfully.'

      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end


   def destroy
       @current_user = nil
       cookies[:auth_token] = nil
       reset_session
       redirect_to root_path
   end

end
```

Comment: Note that some settings of some browsers don't naturally have "sessions" that close. They can keep cookies forever!

Comment: What is the point of having "remember me" then? If I tick (the checkbox) it remembers, if I don't it remembers?

Comment: Some browsers destroy session cookies when the whole browser is closed (which rarely happens anyway as some ppl just keep their browser active and open and close windows). But the restore previous state of the browser, which starts with the exact same windows w/ same URL as when it was previously closed, destroys the concept completely. So it depends a lot on user settings.